# Как "сбросить" строку в Си?

Tags: c, массивы, строки

В коде я считываю число с помощью `scanf()`, после чего начинаю записывать строки в двумерный массив char с помощью функции `gets_s()`

Но была (и есть) проблема, что первая строка в массиве - пустая.

На данном ресурсе мне посоветовали использовать `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`, но у меня это не скомпилировалось, потому что пишу на Си.

Какой аналог данной строчки в Си?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например,

```
while(getchar()!='\n');
```

или

```
scanf("%*[^\n]s%*c");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Первый вариант сработал, второй -- нет.